# How to achieve web-parts-full-width for List Views (OTB) - Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I would like to make the OTB list view have a full width. I want to get rid of the scroll etc.

I have gone through this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column)

I created a web part as suggested and changed the manifest to **"supportsFullBleed": true,**
I can see the web part listed under the web part that you can add a full width but the question is how can I get the OOTB list View to display in full width?

Thanks in advance if there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add OOTB SharePoint list view web part inside your custom SPFx web part.

In SPFx, you can fetch the list items using REST API or SP PnP JS and show it in list view using Fluent UI DetailsList control or PnP ListView control. Check below references for more information about these controls:

1. [Fluent UI DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist)
2. [PnP ListView control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ListView/)

**Similar articles**:

1. [List View in Spfx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/list-view-in-spfx/)
2. [PnP List View Control In SharePoint Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pnp-list-view-control-in-sharepoint-framework/)

Comment: You might able to add the OOTB list view page in SPFx web part using `iframe`. But there may be problems using iframe. So, I don't recommend using iframe/embedding.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the articles. Is there one that enables paging the list by default?

Comment: Pagination is not supported by default.

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does this help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.